# How do I set up a label in my UICollectionView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been struggling with this for almost an entire day now and can't find a solution. I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` within a view controller that has cells just with a single label in each of them. However, I can't seem to add the label as a subview to the cell no matter what I do. Here is the code I have in my main view controller:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  func configureCollectionView()
    {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 20)

        let y = interestsUnderline.frame.origin.y + 5
        let width = interestsUnderline.frame.width
        let frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: y, width: width, height: 30)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.register(InterestsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InterestsCell")
        collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }
```

I call configureCollectionView() from viewDidLayoutSubviews. This is the code I have in my collection view cell.

```
    class InterestsCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView.addSubview(label)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Whenever I dequeue the cell, I get the correct size of the cell and the correct color. But when I go to set constraints on the label in my cell's setupViews function, the view controller will just not even open up altogether. If I don't set the constraints, the label is not there. I'm not sure what to do at this point and I would appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add constraints to your label.  Show the code where you attempted to do that and it didn't work.

Comment: @dan Here it is         label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your above snippet and what I found is you haven't set the `Frame` you need to set the `Frame` of your `UILabel`

```
let label: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 30)
            label.text = "Hello"
            label.textColor = UIColor.red
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return label
        }()
```

Hope this help you

Comment: @ Maddyヅヅ EDIT: This doesn't work because I can't access self.view from that closure for some reason. I can set it to a constant though. But if the label text is wider than the cell frame, then a portion of the text would get cut off. Is there any way to dynamically change the size of the cell frame?

Comment: @AteethKosuri collectionView having sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate you can calculate the estimate width/height of cell on that and you can set the size of cell base on that

Comment: @ Maddyヅヅ When I set the frame of the label to a constant and use the sizeForItemAtIndexPath function to check the width of the label so I can set cell width, the width of the label will stay as that constant so nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your project uses auto layout constraints you have to set them for the label:

```
func setupViews() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your InterestsCell class add the following code:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupViews()
    }
```

instead of:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

Hope this would work